# what is the best approach to fix file-system corruption on huge data

Tags: linux, filesystems, fsck, xfs, e2fsck

we need to fix filesystem corruption on sdb  on redhat 6 version

*sdb is xfs file system*

```
df -h | egrep "Filesystem|/data"
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       8.2T  7.0T  1.0T   86% /data
```

becaus the data on sdb is huge

we want to know what is the best option 1 or 2 ?

or other idea to do the file-system fixing ?

**option 1**

```
umount /data
fsck -y /dev/sdb
mount /data
```

**option 2**

```
umount /data
e2fsck -y /dev/sdb
mount /data
```

**option 3**

```
umount /data
xfs_repair /dev/sdb
mount /data
```

second - what are the risks when doing fsck on huge data ?

Comment: Both of your options listed are the same.

Comment: sorry - I fixed that

Comment: If the filesystem is XFS, why would you try running `e2fsck` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/19984/402107):

> `fsck` is just the original name. When they came out with new file systems they would need a specific tool for each one, `efsck` for ext, `e2fsck` for ext2, `dosfsck`, `fsckvfat`. So they made `fsck` the front end that just calls whichever is the appropriate tool.

```
fsck.xfs
```

is probably what you are after.

---

## XFS-related update:

[`xfs_check`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_check) and [`xfs_repair`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_repair) should help you evaluate the damage and repair if possible.

Please see the manual pages for specific usage information.

Comment: so we can be safe when we do - fsck -y /dev/sdb ?

Comment: @yael That depends, I personally think it is, but this is opinion-based probably.

Comment: so what is better fsck.xfs -y /dev/sdb or fsck -y /dev/sdb

Comment: @yael I think both would do the same job. But I tend to always specify the type, ie. I would use `fsck.xfs`.

Comment: so what is the diff between xfs_repair to fsck.xfs ?

Comment: see my update .

Comment: @yael It seems fsck itself is not able to fix XFS errors, that's why there is the command you mentioned. Unfortunately, I don't have experience with XFS at all to try it out.

Comment: Actually, `fsck.xfs`is like `/bin/true`: it does not really do anything at all. See `man fsck.xfs`. And because `fsck -y /dev/sdb` would just call `fsck.xfs -y /dev/sdb` when it sees that the filesystem type is XFS, that will also do nothing at all. The kind of routine checks other filesystems would do at boot time, XFS has built right into the filesystem driver. `xfs_repair`, on the other hand, is more like `e2fsck -f`.

Answer (score 0):

To the people voting for fsck.xfs ... it's just a renamed version of /bin/true. It does nothing except return '0' and exit. The Proper answer is:

```
umount /data
xfs_repair /dev/sdb
mount /data
```

Comment: You’ll notice that xfs_repair was mentioned in the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441269/117549)